# Making a game in javascript, position does not update correctly

Tags: javascript

I am making a game where when the user presses the space bar, the player jumps so its y coordinate decreases by 1. However calling my movePlayer() function multiple times will increase the jump height for some reason (The first time pressing space will result in the y coordinate decreasing much less than the 10th time). Can someone help me out with this problem? Thanks!

```
this.interval = setInterval(movePlayer, 25);
...
function movePlayer() {
    if (player.y + player.radius < display.canvas.height) {
        player.y++;
    }
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 32) {
        player.y -= 1;
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're adding multiple `keypress` listeners (one every 25 milliseconds). Just move the `document.addEventListener(...)` call outside the `movePlayer` function.

Answer (score 2):

You have stated that *calling my movePlayer() function multiple times will increase the jump height*.

This is the root cause of your problem.  Consider `movePlayer`:

```
function movePlayer() {
    if (player.y + player.radius < display.canvas.height) {
        player.y++;
    }
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        ...
```

The problem here is that every single time you call `movePlayer`, you create a new event listener on the `keypress` event.

The first time you call it, pushing space will run `player.y -= 1;` once.

By the fifth time, you are running `player.y -= 1;` 5 times over!

You only need to add the handler once for the `keypress` event (unless you want it to run *n* times).

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I moved document.addEventListener outside the function and it worked!